# batch modify list of files in R

Tags: r, batch-rename

I'd like to batch rename a series of files using R. My files are called something like "ABC_DD", "ABC_EE", "ABC_FF", etc. and I would like to replace "ABC" with "123" (e.g. "123_DD", "123_EE", etc.) for all of them (it is about 1000 files). Any idea about how to do it?

So far I have tried:

```
old_files <- list.files("folder/", pattern = "*.wav", full.names = TRUE)
file.copy(from = old_files, to = new_files)
```

My problem is that I have not been able to create a file called "new_files", where I replace the "ABC" bit with "123."

Thanks!

Comment: Are you able to rename a single file or is the question about how to do all files at once? Can you share any code?

Comment: All the files at once! I have added two lines of code, if it helps!

Comment: You can use `gsub` to substitute strings like that... `gsub("ABC", "123", "ABC_DD")`